# Implode results into chunks from mysqli_fetch_assoc where perf1_id cannot be in the same chunk

Tags: php, mysqli

So I'm trying to retrieve information from my database , and usually tells gives me an array to string error which is why I implode it. Before displaying the data however I would like to break it into groups of 3 where the same perf1_id cannot appear in the same chunk more than once. This is the code that I have tried so far:

My Query to get the information

```
$query2 = " SELECT * FROM  trial_am";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
```

How I retrieve it and display it:

```
<ul>

<?php while($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
   $one = array_chunk($array, 3, false);
   echo "<li>" ;
   echo implode(" ", $one) ;
   echo"</li>"  ;
}  ?>

</ul>
```

I am still a beginner so any help would be appreciated

Comment: It is unclear what result you actually want to achieve, but your current use of `array_chunk()` will be splitting up your flat row of associative data into chunks.  This means that `$one` is an array of arrays AND `implode()` will want a flat array.  We don't know what is in your `trial_am` table, nor what data is being returned from the `*` in your SELECT clause.  Too much is missing from this question to be valuable to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would divide my result sets in subsets as follows:

```
<?php 
$counter = 1;
while($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
    $resuilt_partial[] = $array ;
    if($counter % 3 == 0)
    {//at each 3rd element append in the final array
        $result_set[] = $resuilt_partial ;
        $resuilt_partial = array();
    }
    $counter++;
} 
foreach($result_set as $result_divided)
{
//$result_divided - contains 3 elements
//add your code here
}
?>
```

**P.S**: mysql_ functions are deprecated

Comment: thank you for your answer,I'd be lying if i said i really understood what to do here, I removed my while statement and replaced it with yours and put an echo statement within the add your code part but I just kept getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php while($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    $one = array_chunk($array, 3, false); 
    echo "<li>" ;
    echo implode(" ", array_map('implode', $one));
    echo"</li>"  ;
 }  ?>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I replaced my code with yours but still got the same result.